# Why do you have to mine 432 blocks to activate segwit on regtest?

Tags: segregated-witness, regtest, activation-mechanism

According to Rusty Russel, you need to mine 432 blocks to activate segwit on regtest. Why this specific blockheight?

Sources:

- https://rusty-lightning.medium.com/segregated-witness-for-developers-8fa9042f43ed#.6ur6kr5nf
- https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/f4e94147a7281ec05e078ff9f3e6d65893417bad/test-cli/scripts/generate-block.sh#L11

Answer (score 5):

Note that since 0.16, Segwit is always active on regtest from the genesis block.

Prior to 0.16, Segwit on regtest is defined to have a start time of 0 and can be activated through the BIP 9 versionbits mechanism. In BIP 9, the genesis block always has the state of `DEFINED`, which means that the signaling period beginning with the genesis block is `DEFINED` and any signaling in that period does not count for segwit.

Segwit would become `STARTED` in the second signaling period and only then would signaling blocks be counted. If the threshold is reached, then it will become `LOCKED_IN` during the third signaling period. Once the third signaling period concludes, Segwit will be active. So under ideal circumstances where all blocks signal for Segwit, 3 signaling periods are needed for Segwit to become active.

In Regtest, each signaling period is 144 blocks. 144 * 3 = 432 blocks need to be mined for Segwit to become active.